# Autocomplete in jQgrid with JSON data returned by a Php page

Tags: php, javascript, json, jqgrid, autocomplete

I was trying to implement autocomplete for a textbox which is generated by jQgrid. A Php page would return JSON data. Here's what I was able to do so far: (Please help)

```
function autocomplete_element(value, options) {
  var $ac = $('<input type="text"/>');
  $ac.val(value);
  $ac.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("autocomplete.php", { q: request.term }, response);
    }
  });
  return $ac;
}

function autocomplete_value(elem, op, value) {
  if (op == "set") {
    $(elem).val(value);
  }
  return $(elem).val();
}

$(function(){

  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'process1.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Column Name'],
    colModel :[ 
        {name:'columnid', index:'columnid', width:50, edittype:'custom', 
            editoptions: {
                custom_element : autocomplete_element,
                custom_value   : autocomplete_value
            }
        }
    ]

........
........




////////////////////////////////////////////////
///         THE PHP PAGE                    ////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
    autocomplete.php
*/


<?php

    require_once("../dbconfig.php");
    $term = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

    $qstring = "SELECT description as value, id FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%".$term."%'";
    $result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
    {
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
    }

    echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data

?>
```

When I use data such as ["blah","hello","howdy"] in source of $ac.autocomplete, the thing seems to work nicely. But I have around 2000 rows of data to search from. The jQgrid form is working correctly and I am being able to add & edit data. Also, I have tested the php page which displays proper JSON data when I point a browser at it. I am only struck with autocomplete with data returned from the php page since I am not much comfortable with jQuery. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding exit() after the last echo in php code. I hope this will fix.